# how to get default printer port number in java

Tags: java

I want to access the default printer port in Java.

Also, I want to know if the default printer is inkjet, laser, dot matrix, etc.
Please provide references.

Comment: @Christopher, please remove salutations when editing rather than making them _bigger_: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/157556 -- the rest of the edit is an improvement, so I intend to hit the "improve" button...

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you are using windows. In such case you can query the windows registry to find the default printer port. All the system information is the Preferences.

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

....

Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
```

There is a good article that explain how to do that using **pure** java:

http://lenkite.blogspot.com/2008/05/access-windows-registry-using-java.html?dzref=85420

Also, you may need to know the key of the default printer in windows:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need the port number ? If you want to print from Java, have you considered the [Java Printing APIs](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/printing/) ?

The reason that I ask is that you may not have a printer attached directly. You may have a networked printer. The JPA will provide you with a more reliable interface for this.